# I need to reduce text segment of all object files used in my project

Tags: c, linux, optimization, memory, memory-management

**My project requirement is to  reduce text segment of object files used in my project. I tried reducing redundant logic but the change results is minimum amount of bytes .**

My code uses switch cases ,nested if/else ,along with const arrays and for/while loops .It also contains semaphores,mutex etc.

Can you please suggest best solution to reduce maximum instruction used in text segment?

Comment: What link-time optimisations are you using?

Comment: gcc standard. LTO

Comment: There's just no one simple or single answer to this. You might use compiler and linker flags to enable space-saving optimization (but those could result in "slower" code). Or you could reduce the actual source code, which could lead to unreadable and unmaintainable code. You could use less constant variables which could be put into the text segment. Or perhaps a myriad of other things, or a combination of many things. But the important point is to remember that no matter what you do it will be a trade-off. You win some in text segment size, but loose in others.

Comment: While this question in it current form is fuzzy and much to broad, I'm curious about the requirement itself? What is the project? What is your target platform? And most importantly, why do you have this requirement and where does it come from? What's the underlying problem it's supposed to solve?

Comment: I need to reduce Ram size from 2gb to 1gb basically firmware requirement and it is Linux platform.

Comment: @JAINILPANDYA What are you coding that takes 2gb of ram? And why are you asking about lowering the text segment when it's obviously something that you are loading from disk or generating from code that takes up 2GB of ram.

Comment: Have you customized the linker file? Have you stripped the executable? Build for 32-bit target? And considering that it wasn't that many years ago that many Linux systems commonly ran with less than a single GiB or RAM, perhaps your code is just badly designed from the start? Does it do a lot of dynamic memory allocations? Contain large arrays? And this sounds more like a systems-integration problem than the problem of a single program (unless it's badly implemented or designed).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks dude ,no customized linker ,we have 64 bit os ,yup our code is old enough and it is not properly designed . Stores in large arrays and less number of dynamic memory allocations. Does increase in dynamic memory allocation decrease text segment size?

Comment: @Fredrik bro, it is new requirement to reduce the overall memory segment so reducing text segment is a part of it. data /.bss memory are up to the mark.

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation from the heap will come out of the same virtual memory pool on the hardware in the end, so for a memory-constrained system it's not a real solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Optimize for size. If you are using GCC, use the flag -Os, which instructs GCC to "optimize for size." It enables all -O2 optimizations which do not increase the size of the executable, and then it also toggles some optimization flags to further reduce executable size.